Sitecore GraphQL search query to get fetch only the latest version of the page
I am trying to get all the pages to meet certain criteria using GraphQL query as below. But this query returns all versions of the page. (We need this in Preview mode of the page)
How can we restrict the query to consider only the latest version of the page? (There is latestVersion parameter for the search query tried using this in the Search query parameter. But it gives an error. Probably it is not the correct way of using this parameter).
    query GetBlogs(
      $after: String
      $language: String!
      $numberOfPages: Int
      $pageName: String!
      $rootFolderId: String!
      $tagFilter: ItemSearchPredicateInput
    ) {
      pageResults: search(
        where: {
          AND: [
            { name: "_language", operator: EQ, value: $language }
            { name: "_hasLayout", value: "true" }
            {
              name: "_templates"
              operator: CONTAINS
              value: "acd3828a-d5b4-41fa-8a1e-1030e28b0c9a"
            }
            $tagFilter
            { name: "_name", operator: NEQ, value: $pageName }
            { name: "_path", operator: CONTAINS, value: $rootFolderId }
          ]
        }
        orderBy: { name: "date", direction: DESC }
    
        first: $numberOfPages
    
        after: $after
      ) {
        total
    
        pageInfo {
          endCursor
    
          hasNext
        }
    
        results {
          ...SearchBlogs
    
       
        }
      }
    }
    
    fragment SearchBlogs on C__AppRoute {
      id
    
      language {
        name
      }
    
      metaDescription {
        jsonValue
      }
    
      file {
        jsonValue
      }
    
      picture {
        jsonValue
      }
    
      url {
        path
      }
    
      pageTitle {
        jsonValue
      }
    
      tags {
        id
    
        jsonValue
      }
    }

Thanks,
Shrutika

The Search Query in experience edge will return only the latest version. Are you getting all versions details in Edge also?

We need this latest version in Preview mode. I have updated the question as well

You can try latestVersion parameter like
$tagFilter
        { name: "_name", operator: NEQ, value: $pageName }
        { name: "_path", operator: CONTAINS, value: $rootFolderId }
        { name: "_latestVersion", value: "true" }

Or you can try filter in code like
results.forEach(item => {
    if (!latestVersions[item.id] || latestVersions[item.id].version < item.version) {
      latestVersions[item.id] = item;
    }
  });

Hope this helps!!!

Thanks Ajay.!
It gives error
"message": "The field '_latestVersion' is not supported. The list of available predefined fields: '_name', '_path', '_parent', '_templates', '_hasLayout' and '_language'.",

Then I guess it should be filter in code!

yes thanks @Ajay Gour
